# Phonegap Blackberry Sign Application steps

Tags: cordova, blackberry-10

How to sign and create certificate and install blackberry application.

So any one here who can let me describe steps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sdk path : C:\Program Files\Research In Motion\BlackBerry 10 WebWorks SDK 1.0.4.11

Install apache ant : set sys path "http://uwudamith.wordpress.com/tag/how-to-install-apache-ant-in-windows/"

build project :navigate to project folder and cmd command  : ant blackberry build

Register with server : blackberry-signer -register -csjpin glare123 -cskpass g****@123 client-RDK-2038600.csj

sign app : blackberry-signer -storepass g***@123 ****.bar

(Navigate to sdk path bin folder)install app : blackberry-deploy -installApp -password glare@123 -device 192.168.199.128 -package RadioBiafra.bar  -password ****@123

dubug token : blackberry-debugtokenrequest -register -csjpin glare@123 -storepass ***@123 client-RDK-2064575.csj

Ref site : http://inflagrantedelicto.memoryspiral.com/2011/02/blackberry-playbook-code-signing-process/